# Can anyone explain the working of this code on permuting strings in c?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, math, permutation

Function permute() to print permutations of string
    This function takes three parameters:
    1. String
    2. Starting index of the string
    3. Ending index of the string.

```
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
 char temp;
 temp = *x;
 *x = *y;
 *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *a, int i, int n) 
{
 int j; 
 if (i == n)
  printf("%s\n", a);
 else
 {
     for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
    {
       swap((a+i), (a+j));
       permute(a, i+1, n);
       swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
    }
 }
} 

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
 char a[] = "ABC";  
 permute(a, 0, 2);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can start by putting the algorithm on paper and analyze.

Comment: I'm new to programming so I didn't get the meaning of char* + int in the swap function call.

Comment: Check the answer below. Hope it addresses your query. And, please, in future, please narrow down your problem statement, ok? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments follow-up, IMO, what you want to understand is

```
swap((a+i), (a+j));
```

function call.

Well, to start with, in `void permute()` function, you're accepting the first parameter as `char *a`. So, `a` is of type `char *`, and `int i, int n` are two more integers.

Now, while calling `swap()` function, as per the function signature, you need to pass the address of a char variable as both the parameters of `swap()`. There. `(a + i)` and `(a+j)` are being used.

To clarify, `a` is a pointer, and adding another integer `i` [or `j`] to it means, *incrementing* the pointer by that many positions [elements] of the value `i`.

so,

- `a + 0` will point to the first element.
- `a+1` will return the address of the next [2nd] `char` element in
  `a`.
- `a+2` will return the address of the 3rd `char` element in `a`

..

and so on.

*Related reading:* From `C99` standard document, chapter 6.5.6, paragraph 2, [emphasis mine]

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, ***or one operand shall be a pointer to an object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is
>   equivalent to adding 1.)***